# How to augment the ASP.NET Core validation to ignore some properties and validate on a value that is a function of that property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, model-binding

I have an `Optional` class taken from Roslyn: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Optional.cs

The gist of it:

```cs
public readonly struct Optional<T>
{
    public Optional(T value)
    {
        _hasValue = true;
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool HasValue => _hasValue;

    public T Value => _hasValue 
        ? _value
        : throw new InvalidOperationException("Optional object must have a value");
}
```

Now I want to use this class in the ASP.NET request model so that a user can set arbitrary properties of said model during an update request to perform a partial update.

This works fine in itself and I get a proper model, but the problem arises when I want to add validation (and rather re-use standard validation) attributes.

These two problems pop up:

1. Validation tries to read `Value` and throw an exception (when it tries to visit children) when the field is not set
2. If the field is set, the validation attributes would not get the `Value` properly and would try to validate the struct itself

I am not sure if I am trying to solve it correctly, but I was wondering if somehow I can alter the validation of an `Optional` field, or an object containing such fields, so that all fields that are not set would be ignored from the validation, and the ones that are set would validate on `.Value` instead of the struct itself.

P.S. I cannot use `Nullable<T>` because I want to differentiate a null value and an absence of value. I.e. a field with a null value means: update the field to `null`, no field means - do not change that field. This is an attempt to model the undefined from json. So e.g. I would have Optional<string?> and Optional<long?> if corresponding field can accept null.

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in implementing IValidateableObject, which lets you write custom code to validate things on when deserializing. Reusing standard validation might be difficult, although could be doable if you use Nullable<T> rather than Optional<T> as it's embedded deeper in the language.

Comment: I also don't understand what's the difference between the Nullable and optional for the validation for this model.

Comment: I have added some details to the question why Nullable does not work in this case

Comment: @BrandoZhang A _real_ `Option<T>` type would allow programs to differentiate between `null` and `undefined` - C# does give us `Nullable<T>` but it's only compatible with `struct`-types and cannot be used to represent `undefined` vs. `null`, hence why there's many third-party (and even multiple first-party) attempts at implementing an `Option<T>` type, but limitations inherent in C#/.NET's type-system and generics support mean that they all suffer from some cruel limitation of some kind.